# What is the maximum value of a number in Apache CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I would like to store a number in Apache CouchDB, what is the maximum value that one is able to store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchdb stores JSON. So the biggest number it can store is the biggest number allowed in JSON. Which is [9007199254740992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Try inserting a 9007199254740993 in couchdb via futon and it will immediately revert it back to 9007199254740992.